# Angular 2+ Enter animation on child component works but leave does not

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

i have a sub component like this

```
@Component({
selector: 'is-time-controlled',
templateUrl: './is-time-controlled.html',
styleUrls: ['./is-time-controlled.less'],
animations: [
    trigger(
        'myAnimation',
        [
            transition(
                ':enter', [
                    style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
                    animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', 'opacity': 1 }))
                ]
            ),
            transition(
                ':leave', [
                    style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }),
                    animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', 'opacity': 0 }))
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
]
```

})

and the sub component has a template with first div like this

```
<div class="card card-padding" [@myAnimation]>
```

parent component has *ngIf

```
 <is-time-controlled  *ngIf="somelogic"> </is-time-controlled>
```

when logic is true i see enter animation but when logic becomes false i dont see leaving animation.

i see various opened issues. do we have a fix for this?

Comment: You need to put the animation on the is-time-controlled component.

Comment: yes it is there. and [@myAnimation] is on the first div of "is-time-controlled"

Comment: It has to be on the is-time-controlled component.

Comment: Yes it is there already

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try like this:

```
animations: [trigger('myAnimation', [
            state('enter', style({
                transform: 'translateX(100%)';
                opacity: '0';
            })),
            state('leave', style({
                transform: 'translateX(0)';
                opacity: '1';
            })),
            transition('enter <=> leave', [animate(500)])
        ]
    )]
```

This creates two states. All you have to do now is to create a variable to fetch the state, right after changing 'somelogic' to true/false

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public state: string;
    public somelogic: boolean;

    function1(): any {
        this.somelogic = true;
        this.state = 'enter';
    }

    function2(): any {
        this.somelogic = false;
        this.state = 'leave';
    }
}
```

In your HTML

```
<div class="card card-padding" [@myAnimation]="state">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: somelogic  is in parent so where should i create the "state" variable? .
[@myAnimation]="state" is in child component's first <div> how will it know what is "state"

Comment: I changed the response, didn't see you were not using state(). If you create a state variable in your component (which is rendering your HTML), you can use it in HTML (if it's declared as public)

Comment: so i created "state" string object in parent component and setting it "enter" and "leave" appropriately but no animation is working now. looking into it ...

Comment: and ";" in the code you wrote were actually "," in my case as that is an object properties.

Comment: state is not boolean but a string ! 'somelogic' is the boolean you were using from the beginning

Comment: yeah sorry that was typo :)

Comment: and you used state() method instead of transition() ?

Comment: yes exactly same code and one transition at the end like in your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085604/angular-animation-leave-transition-on-child-div          this said that angular does not play leave animation.

Comment: U_U i'll note that,n you don't have to put it into a *ngIf. You can still make it disappear with css in your animation, ending up with a display:none;